# How to perform aggregation (eg. avg) on list of objects in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl, aws-elasticsearch

I have data in the following form in Elasticsearch:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "abc",
        "score": 10,
        "values": [
            {
                "v1": 1,
                "v2": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "def",
        "score": 20,
        "values": [
            {
                "v1": 3,
                "v2": 4
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Currently, I am calculating average on `score` using the following code:

```
s = Search(using=es, index=index).query(Q(query))
s.aggs.bucket('average_score', 'avg', field='score') # average_score = 15
```

Now I wish to compute average on `v1` and `v2` using `elasticsearch_dsl` but I don't know how to do nested aggregation. In this example, `v1 = 2` and `v2 = 3`. Please help. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** **Unfortunately, here `values` is an object instead of nested.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea how to do it in your DSL but here are the raw steps.

---

Mapping:

```
PUT avgs/
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "values": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "v1": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "v2": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Indexing:

```
POST avgs/_doc
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "abc",
  "score": 10,
  "values": [
    {
      "v1": 1,
      "v2": 2
    }
  ]
}

POST avgs/_doc
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "def",
  "score": 20,
  "values": [
    {
      "v1": 3,
      "v2": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Querying:

```
GET avgs/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "avg_v1": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "values"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested_v1": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "values.v1"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "avg_v2": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "values"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested_v2": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "values.v2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Yielding:

```
...
  "aggregations" : {
    "avg_v2" : {
      "doc_count" : 2,
      "nested_v2" : {
        "value" : 3.0
      }
    },
    "avg_v1" : {
      "doc_count" : 2,
      "nested_v1" : {
        "value" : 2.0
      }
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Is it possible to do the same without changing the type of `value` to `nested`? If yes, what is it? If not, I already have a mapping where it is not of `nested` type and has the data. Is it possible to update the existing mapping?

Comment: It's possible to update the existing mapping but you'll still need to reindex. Changing the mapping doesn't reindex by itself. BTW why do you need `values` to be `nested`? If you aggregate `v1` and `v2` separately, you don't need keep track of the "connection" between them. More info at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested

Comment: What I'm saying is, you can aggregate just the way it's set up already, without `nested`: `{"size":0,"aggs":{"avg_v1":{"avg":{"field":"values.v1"}},"avg_v2":{"avg":{"field":"values.v2"}}}}`

Comment: Meanwhile I was looking for a way to fix nested field type and I did exactly what you said. And it works! Thanks! :)